# Autodesk Forge API: "this account doesn't exist." error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

When POSTing to:
[https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/regions/eu/accounts{AccountId}/projects](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/regions/eu/accounts%7BAccountId%7D/projects)
I get:

Error 404 Not Found

```
{
    "code": 1004,
    "message": "this account doesn't exist."
}
```

As I understand the AccountId is the hubId and it exists since
[https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b.{AccountId}](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b.%7BAccountId%7D) returns the account info.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds the account is is not correct. When you integrate your web app (Forge client id) with the account, have you made a note with the account id?

[image]

or this id can also be found at browser address when you log  in the module Account>>Admin
[image]

In addition, does your BIM account locate in US or EMEA? If US, it will not work using /regions/eu/

If you still have the problem, please send us the question at forge.help@autodesk.com with your account id. We can check at backend.

If you still have the problem,

Comment: The extra /regions/eu/ was the problem. Our production is located in EMEA but the test environment was provisioned in the US.